# can I edite Laravel project from my serveur directly

Tags: laravel, customization, editing

I have a website that creates from Laravel. I want to do some customization to that.

Can I edit directly from my server or need anysoftwair or anything else

I need help editing it. How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the files directly on your server using any text editor available to you, however, it's not advisable to make changes directly on a live/production environment. What happens if/when you make a mistake or a change has a negative effect (e.g. on performance), how will you revert those changes efficiently and swiftly, and how will you know which file(s) are causing any issue(s)?

Instead create a local environment to make and test your changes, ideally then deploy those changes to a remote staging/development environment for further testing before deploying to your live/production environment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have created a copy of my project in a subdomain so that I can test it, so I will avoid any issues with my main project.